# Como configurar as rotas no asterisk ?

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk

Colegas venho através deste post trazer mais uma duvida para a comunidade, estou realizando uma configuração em uma central Asterisk que anteriormente possuía 4 chips de 4 operadoras distintas. Agora esta central possuiu apenas 2 chips de uma determinada operadora, antes ao realizar a ligação o usuario digitava o numero que gostaria de ligar e era feita uma consulta em um sistema de consulta de operadoras este sistema identificava o numero e o direcionava para qual chip seria melhor.

Porem agora não há mais a necessidade da utilização deste serviço, desativei este serviço pelo Elastix web e observei que se caso ligue apenas o numero do celular é apresentado uma mensagem informando que houve uma falha ao consulta a operadora, porem realizando a ligação com o 021 + DDD + Numero a ligação é feita normalmente.

Gostaria de saber com defino que todas as ligações devem sair do jeito que preciso.

Comment: Olá!Como você está administrando o asterisk? Diretamente pelos arquivos de configuração ou utilizando a interface Web? Qual a versão você está utilizando (do Elastix, por exemplo)?